# Get Top 10 values in Google Sheets Pivot Table

Tags: filter, google-sheets, pivot

I have a Google Sheets pivot table with sales values of transactions in descending order. I want to modify the pivot table to only show the Top 10 sales values. The source data for the pivot table is being updated daily, so naturally, the Top 10 values will be changing as time progresses.

How can I do this in Google Sheets?

Comment: max you can do is to query it out and then construct pivot table

Answer (score 2):

directly in the pivot table, it's not possible so you need to use some formula to trim it and then use pivot table from there:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "limit 10")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

There is a good function in Google Sheets called SORTN which return any number of values in a range sorted as you want.

Use it on another sheet, the data will update automatically when value in the source range change.